# Creating separate class file functions that take parameters C++

Tags: c++

Pretty simple question but I couldn't find an answer regarding this specific question which surprised me.

I get a string of errors when attempting to call a class function that changes a private class string.

Edit: I have solved the problem - I forgot to include the required namespace and assembly references in the header file.

Here is the .h file code:

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();
    string getName();
    void setName(string animalName);
private:
string name;
};

#endif
```

here is the class .cpp:

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

Animal::Animal()
{

}


Animal::~Animal()
{
}

void Animal::setName(string animalName)
{
name = animalName;
}

string Animal::getName()
{
return name;
}
```

finally,here is the int main(),where I have attempted to call the functions (I just got a bunch of errors upon compiling)

```
int main()
{
Animal chicken;

chicken.setName("gary");

cout << chicken.getName() << endl;

_getch();
}
```

Error messages include:

`error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'`

`error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

```
`error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getName'`
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You forgot to say what the error code(s) and error message(s) are, and what line(s) they are happening on.

Comment: @Pharap that was the problem,thank you. didn't realise assembly references were needed in the .h file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include `<string>` in your header. The string object also lives in the `std` namespace so you need provide a fully qualified name to use it (don't add `using namespace` to headers).

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>  // You need to include this

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();
    std::string getName();
    void setName(std::string animalName);
private:
    std::string name;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class header is missing string library declaration and std:: before each string declaration.

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

#include <string>

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();
    std::string getName();
    void setName(std::string animalName);
private:
std::string name;
};

#endif
```

@edit
Up

You beat me to it! Your answer showed up just when I posted mine